# how to pass multiple params in url through javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an if-else condition in javascript. In every else condition I want to pass a parameter id with its value in url on & basis like in first else condition code passed a value 5 with id variable.

```
http://localhost/cah/blank.php?id=5
```

in second condition

```
http://localhost/cah/blank.php?id=5&id=9
```

and so on. Likewise I can have multiple conditions in which I have to pass different values of id in url. how can it be done? Either by storing them all in an array or pass values in url on & basis but without refreshing page.

```
var count=0;
var counts=0;

function check() {
    var a = document.getElementById("div1") ;
    var b = document.getElementById('div1').getAttribute('value');

    if (a.textContent==b){
        count++;
        var p1=document.getElementById('cnt');
        p1.value=count;
        a.style.color = "green";
    }
    else { 
        counts++;
        a.style.color = "Red";
        window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "./blank.php?id=<? echo $id;?>");
        $('#d<? echo $d3++;?>').addClass('disabled');
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid it's not at all clear what you're asking. Would you please edit the question to clarify? One thing to do is to either ask a question about JavaScript (removing the PHP tag and all PHP code from the question), or ask a question about PHP (removing the JavaScript tag).

Comment: you can only have one valid instance of `id` in the querystring but you could pass multiple values in an array in the querystring, like `?id=[1,2,3,4,5]`

Comment: sir how i can store all id values in an array without refreshing the page. plz suggest

Answer (score 0):

Use array-style names for the parameters:

```
http://localhost/cah/blank.php?id[]=5&id[]=9
```

PHP will then make `$_GET['id']` return an array of all the parameters.

```js
var ids = [5, 9];
var id_params = ids.map(function(id) {
  return 'id[]=' + id;
}).join('&');
var url = 'http://localhost/cah/blank.php?' + id_params;
console.log(url);
```

In PHP it would be:

```
<?php
$ids = array(5, 9);
$id_params = implode('&', array_map(function($id) {
    return 'id[]=' . $id;
}, $ids));
?>
window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "./blank.php?<?php echo $id_params;?>");
```

Comment: 5 & 9 are not fixed. i can have many values of id. after triggering else condition

Comment: That's just an example. If you have an array of IDs, use a loop to add them all to the URL in this way.

Comment: like first i have id value is 5,then it have 6, then 8, so i have to store all 5,6,8 values in an array

Comment: Then it would be `?id[]=5&id[]=6&id[]=8`.

Comment: that's my question sir, how to send values of id in url on & basis. i am using window.history.pushState to send id value to url. it replaces id value but not concatenate new value to url

Comment: I've added a code example showing how to build the URL dynamically.

Comment: However you were going to do it with `id=`, just change that to `id[]=`.

Comment: i want ?id[]=5&id[]=6&id[]=8. but i am getting blank.php?id[]=5, then blank.php?id[]=6, then blank.php?id[]=8

Comment: i have done sir id[]..but it is not concatenating value but replacing

Comment: Then you're not concatenating it properly in a loop.

Comment: Are you doing this in PHP or Javascript? The code in your question gets the ID from PHP, but there's only one `$id` variable. If you want multiple IDs, where do they come from?

Comment: can you please provide me code for this. which i have provided you..kindly change on that

Comment: I've added the PHP version.

Comment: thanks for that sir. but how to prepare that var ids array like i am getting one by one value after triggering else condition

Comment: we can use push method or anything ?? plz suggest. badly stucked to this

Comment: I don't know where the IDs come from, that's a different part of your script. You say you want to put multiple IDs in the URL, surely you know where to get them from.

Comment: i am getting value in <? echo $id;?>.. how to store all these values one by one in an script array  i.e 5,6,8 etc from php $id.

Comment: How many times can I say it? You need to change the code that determines `$id` so that it creates an array of all the IDs that you want to put in the URL. I have no idea where it's coming from, so I can't be any more specific. Only you know where the list of all IDs comes from. What kind of programmer are you if you can't figure this out?